# Passing pandas output of xlsx file as input to a function and have it converted to a csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

I have a xlsx file saved as

```
df_v0[cols].to_excel('{}/{}.xlsx'.format(parent_folder, child_folder), index=False)
```

I am trying to convert this file saved above to csv.

I am able to do it using the below code:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('File Path')
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
output = open('outputfile.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
output.close()
```

I am trying to have the xlsx file saved in the first line to be passed in to the File Path mentioned in the code to convert to csv so that the conversion happens as part of a script. Could anyone guide as to how could I have this passed. Thanks..

Comment: Why not use [`pd.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

Comment: @jpp, I am trying to merge list of xls files into one and then convert to csv and hence using this approach of making one master xls file and then convert it to csv

Comment: OK, I think you'll find converting and appending to a single csv file is likely much more efficient. `to_excel` is usually slow.

Comment: Oh ok. But any idea how could I pass in the path of the xlsx file to the open_workbook command I mentioned above. This will help see how it performs..

Answer (score 0):

To read and excel file you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

```
df = pandas.read_excel("path.xlsx", sheet_name = X, ...)
```

Then you can append the dataframe df with

```
df.append( "what you want to add" )
```

and overwrite your excel file

```
df.to_excel("path.xlsx")
```

With this way you will be able to load all your excel files and concat them into one

```
df1 = pandas.read_excel("path.xlsx", sheet_name = X, ...) 
df2 = pandas.read_excel("path.xlsx", sheet_name = Y, ...)
frame = [df1,df2]
final_df = pd.concat(frame) 
final_df.to_excel("path")
```